# How to get site url with twig in Views custom text?

Tags: views, theming, 8

In Drupal 8 I try to get the absolute site url in a Views custom text field.

I added `{{ url('view.frontpage.page_1') }}` which gives me example.com/node

[Drupal docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates) say `{{ url('view.frontpage') }}` would do it, but it just gives me wsod and throws an error like so:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\RouteNotFoundException: "Route "view.frontpage" does not exist." at /../../docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php line 187\n'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation could be out of date. Check your `router` table for the name of the route. In my Drupal 8 site it is `view.frontpage.page_1`.

Comment: I understand that each module can have a `.routing.yml` file. But I don't know what you mean by `router` table. What do you mean by it and where can i find it?

Comment: It's a database table.